# Failed Trying to use Extensions - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, exc-bad-access

I've recently read `The Swift Programming Language document`, which introduced to me Extensions,  and so I tried to implement this code:

```
extension SKTexture{
    var size: CGSize {
        return self.size()
    }
}
```

Later in the same code, I try to access a property of the SKTexture:

```
someTexture.size.width
```

However, when I run the app, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS[image]

I have also noticed that even if I don't try to access the width property via my new computed property, implementing `someTexture.size().width` instead of `someTexture.size.width` , I get this error. Could someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Short answer:***

For a class derived from `NSObject`, a Swift property
which has the **same name** as an existing Objective-C method **replaces** that method.

Therefore in your case,

```
var size: CGSize {
    return self.size()
}
```

**calls itself recursively** until the  program aborts with a stack overflow
(well, that's what this site is for :).

If you choose a different name for the property, e.g.

```
var theSize: CGSize {
    return self.size()
}
```

then everything works nicely.

---

***Long answer:***

`SKTexture` is a subclass of `NSObject`. Therefore all Swift properties are 
"Objective-C compatible". As a consequence, the compiler generates a getter 
method that can be called from Objective-C code. The getter method for the
`size` property is a `-size` method. So you have now two `-size` methods: 
The original one from `SKTexture` and a second one defined in your Swift code.

If you do the same with your own Objective-C class defined in the same project
then you will get a linker warning:

> instance method 'size' in category from /Users/.../main.o overrides
>   method from class in /Users/.../MyClass.o

If the Objective-C class is defined in a external framework (as in your case)
the linker does not notice the conflict.

Now `return self.size()` calls the generated Objective-C getter method, which in turn
calls the extension method. This leads to "infinite" recursion and ultimately
to a stack overflow.

This is confirmed by the stack backtrace which you can get with the lldb `bt`
command when the program has crashed:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x3d2ef, 0x000000010fb15e01 libobjc.A.dylib`objc::DenseMapBase, unsigned long, true, objc::DenseMapInfo > >, DisguisedPtr, unsigned long, objc::DenseMapInfo >, true>::FindAndConstruct(DisguisedPtr const&) + 21, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff51b9cfe8)
    frame #0: 0x000000010fb15e01 libobjc.A.dylib`objc::DenseMapBase, unsigned long, true, objc::DenseMapInfo > >, DisguisedPtr, unsigned long, objc::DenseMapInfo >, true>::FindAndConstruct(DisguisedPtr const&) + 21
    frame #1: 0x000000010fb13e14 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_object::sidetable_retain() + 94
  * frame #2: 0x000000010d8674d9 cdtest2`ext.cdtest2.ObjectiveC.SKTexture.size.getter : C.CGSize(self=0x00007fcceea020f0) + 25 at AppDelegate.swift:19
    frame #3: 0x000000010d867542 cdtest2`@objc ext.cdtest2.ObjectiveC.SKTexture.size.getter : C.CGSize + 34 at AppDelegate.swift:0
    frame #4: 0x000000010d8674ed cdtest2`ext.cdtest2.ObjectiveC.SKTexture.size.getter : C.CGSize(self=0x00007fcceea020f0) + 45 at AppDelegate.swift:19
    frame #5: 0x000000010d867542 cdtest2`@objc ext.cdtest2.ObjectiveC.SKTexture.size.getter : C.CGSize + 34 at AppDelegate.swift:0
    frame #6: 0x000000010d8674ed cdtest2`ext.cdtest2.ObjectiveC.SKTexture.size.getter : C.CGSize(self=0x00007fcceea020f0) + 45 at AppDelegate.swift:19
    frame #7: 0x000000010d867542 cdtest2`@objc ext.cdtest2.ObjectiveC.SKTexture.size.getter : C.CGSize + 34 at AppDelegate.swift:0
    frame #8: 0x000000010d8674ed cdtest2`ext.cdtest2.ObjectiveC.SKTexture.size.getter : C.CGSize(self=0x00007fcceea020f0) + 45 at AppDelegate.swift:19
    ... 
    frame #149556: 0x000000010d8674ed cdtest2`ext.cdtest2.ObjectiveC.SKTexture.size.getter : C.CGSize(self=0x00007fcceea020f0) + 45 at AppDelegate.swift:19
    frame #149557: 0x000000010d867542 cdtest2`@objc ext.cdtest2.ObjectiveC.SKTexture.size.getter : C.CGSize + 34 at AppDelegate.swift:0
    frame #149558: 0x000000010d8694e0 cdtest2`cdtest2.AppDelegate.application (application=0x00007fccee8005a0, launchOptions=None, self=0x00007fccebc06410)(ObjectiveC.UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : Swift.Optional>) -> Swift.Bool + 112 at AppDelegate.swift:83
    frame #149559: 0x000000010d8697b0 cdtest2`@objc cdtest2.AppDelegate.application (cdtest2.AppDelegate)(ObjectiveC.UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : Swift.Optional>) -> Swift.Bool + 560 at AppDelegate.swift:0
    ...
    frame #149572: 0x000000010d86bcaa cdtest2`main + 42 at AppDelegate.swift:0
    frame #149573: 0x00000001102f0145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

This (hopefully) explains also why the problem occurs with both `someTexture.size().width` and `someTexture.size.width`:
In both cases, the custom extension method is called.

Comment: Okay, thank you a lot! I didn't know about this LLDB debuger until now. I guess this is something I should have learned before...